# Powershell rename and move file every day

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I would like to create a powershell which must rename a file by adding the current date  then move it to another folder (ie.e to archive it). the script should be automatically executed every day at a specific start time (10:OO PM)

I wonder if someone could help me to do that.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

this is not how stackoverflow works but i had this  part ready

> $destpath = 'C:\TEMP\XMLTRANS\Backup\'+(get-date -Format
>   yyyyMMddHHmm)+'.xml' $sourcepath = 'C:\TEMP\XMLTRANS\FILE.xml'
>
> Move-Item -Path $sourcepath -Destination $destpath

you can run this script behind a scheduler or Cron

hope it help !

Answer (score 0):

This script will rename a file with the addition of a date/time stamp and move to an another folder.

A mention to @alex above as I used his script and made a slight change. I wanted to keep the original file name but add the date/time stamp. Thank you Alex, very simple script for a newbie like me :)

```
$fileName = 'My Test File_'
$destpath = 'G:\ArchiveFolder\'+ $filename + (get-date -Format yyyyMMddHHmm)+'.sql' 

$sourcepath = 'G:\OriginalFolder\My Test File.sql'

Move-Item -Path $sourcepath -Destination $destpath
```

Hope it helps?

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to improve your code block formatting. See [answer]